# UINavigationController overlap navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, koloda

I have a UINavigationController similar to this one

[image]

I have elements on the screen which are animated to move across the screen.(https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda) I want those elements to overlap with the navigation bar. Now when the navigation bar simply clips these views. I tried removing clipToBounds from several places without results.

Comment: Try self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true

Comment: @pkc456 this won't work as this only provides some blurry-like effect for the content below but I want to have my elements appear over the bar as they animate.